# Space two objects within a row in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, row, spacing

I know similar questions have been posted here but nothing I've found so far has helped me with my problem.  I'm a beginner with Flutter so I need a bit of help. I am trying to build a simple weather app.  I want to position the days of the week and the highs/lows of that day so that they sit as far apart as possible and both edges line up with each other.  [Currently, my app looks this (I added the red container to help understand).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF7Mk.png). The day of the week and temperature are hugging each other which is what I'm trying to fix.

I have tried using mainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, spaceBetween, and spaceAround but none of those move the text at all.  I've tried using Spacer() but that makes the temperatures disappear.

I have a separate class to build each day because I'm pulling from an api.  That class looks like this:

```
   class WeatherReport extends StatelessWidget {
       final String _day;
       final String _tempMax;
       final String _tempMin;


       WeatherReport(this._day, this._tempMax, this._tempMin);

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
            child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_day, style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                    )
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Text(_tempMax + " | ", style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                            )
                            ),
                            Opacity(
                                opacity: 0.5,
                                child: Text(_tempMin, style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                                )
                                ),
                            ),
                        ],),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                 );
               }
              }
```

I call this class in my main build file.  Here I created a column to house each row that is created by the previous class.  That code looks like this:

```
    Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
       children: <Widget>[
           WeatherReport(days[0], '${(forecast.days[0].main.tempMax).round()}º', '${(forecast.days[1].main.tempMin).round()}º'),
           WeatherReport(days[1], '${(forecast.days[8].main.tempMax).round()}º', '${(forecast.days[9].main.tempMin).round()}º'),
           WeatherReport(days[2], '${(forecast.days[16].main.tempMax).round()}º', '${(forecast.days[17].main.tempMin).round()}º'),
           WeatherReport(days[3], '${(forecast.days[24].main.tempMax).round()}º', '${(forecast.days[25].main.tempMin).round()}º'),
           WeatherReport(days[4], '${(forecast.days[32].main.tempMax).round()}º', '${(forecast.days[33].main.tempMin).round()}º'),
         ],
       ),
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  I figure the answer is simple but I cannot figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your Text Widget with an Expanded:

```
Expanded(
  child: Text(
    _day,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    ),
  ),
),
```

This way the text and the temperature will be as far as possible of each other.

Comment: When I add this, all the text disappears.  Not sure why.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I fixed it.  I added expanded widgets to both text widgets and then wrapped the column in a sized box.  Thanks for your help.